# How to cheaply send a delay message?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

My requirement is very simple, which is a very reasonable requirement in many programs. It is to send a specified message to my `Channel` after a specified time.

I've checked `tokio` for topics related to `delay`, `interval` or `timeout`, but none of them seem that straightforward to implement.

What I've come up with now is to `spawn` an asynchronous task, then `wait` or `sleep` for a certain amount of time, and finally send the message.

But, obviously, spawning an asynchronous task is a relatively heavy operation. Is there a better solution?

```rust
async fn my_handler(sender: mpsc::Sender<i32>, dur: Duration) {
    tokio::spawn(async {
        time::sleep(dur).await;
        sender.send(0).await;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could always `time::sleep(dur).then (|_| async { sender.send (0).await })`, but you will still need to either `await` it yourself or `spawn` it to have tokio `await` it for you.

Comment: I haven't used tokio (yet), but from [their tutorial page](https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial/spawning) - "Tasks in Tokio are very lightweight. Under the hood, they require only a single allocation and 64 bytes of memory. Applications should feel free to spawn thousands, if not millions of tasks." - This suggests your simple solution is correct, but I'm not experienced with this crate, and so won't submit an answer to that effect, but thought I'd point it out here that it's what the doc says at least.

Comment: @KevinAnderson ,thank you. The async task is indeed very lightweight compared to the native thread. But for sending and receiving messages, it is still a heavy operation. If the system provides a timer pool management task, and provides a API to post funture to this task, fire it at expected time, which is managed by it, then the use of timers will be much simpler and more efficient.

Comment: @Jmb `A.then(|_| B)` isn't much different from the `async { A.await; B.await; }` which progquester uses, is it? I.e. it doesn't help at all, does it?

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a second channel and a continuously running task that buffers messages until the time they are to be received. Implementing this is more involved than it sounds, I hope I'm handling cancellations right here:

```
fn make_timed_channel<T: Ord + Send + Sync + 'static>() -> (Sender<(Instant, T)>, Receiver<T>) {
    // Ord is an unnecessary requirement arising from me stuffing both the Instant and the T into the Binary heap
    // You could drop this requirement by using the priority_queue crate instead

    let (sender1, receiver1) = mpsc::channel::<(Instant, T)>(42);
    let (sender2, receiver2) = mpsc::channel::<T>(42);
    let mut receiver1 = Some(receiver1);
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        let mut buf = std::collections::BinaryHeap::<Reverse<(Instant, T)>>::new();
        loop {
            // Pretend we're a bounded channel or exit if the upstream closed
            if buf.len() >= 42 || receiver1.is_none() {
                match buf.pop() {
                    Some(Reverse((time, element))) => {
                        sleep_until(time).await;
                        if sender2.send(element).await.is_err() {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    None => break,
                }
            }
            // We have some deadline to send a message at
            else if let Some(Reverse((then, _))) = buf.peek() {
                if let Ok(recv) = timeout_at(*then, receiver1.as_mut().unwrap().recv()).await {
                    match recv {
                        Some(recv) => buf.push(Reverse(recv)),
                        None => receiver1 = None,
                    }
                } else {
                    if sender2.send(buf.pop().unwrap().0 .1).await.is_err() {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            // We're empty, wait around
            else {
                match receiver1.as_mut().unwrap().recv().await {
                    Some(recv) => buf.push(Reverse(recv)),
                    None => receiver1 = None,
                }
            }
        }
    });
    (sender1, receiver2)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5db3dcb9ad58e25ede0251f7e4de6406)

Whether this is more efficient than spawning tasks, you'd have to benchmark. (I doubt it. Tokio iirc has some much fancier solution than a `BinaryHeap` for waiting for waking up at the next timeout, e.g.)

One optimization you could make if you don't need a `Receiver<T>` but just something that `.poll().await` can be called on: You could drop the second channel and maintain the `BinaryHeap` inside a custom receiver.

Comment: thank you very much. But I am looking for a simple and straightforward method. So I will not accept your answer now. Waiting for someone others suggestion.

Comment: The simple and straightforward method is to spawn a task, I doubt there is anything else. You can spawn about 1 million tasks or send 5 million messages through an mpsc channel per second (1 thread on my 8 year old notebook). So spawning tasks already isn't orders-of-magnitude heavier than sending messages. And what you want is inherently more complex than just sending messages: if messages are supposed to be received at a certain time, they may need to be reordered in the channel. Anyhow: have you benchmarked how high the overall impact of this single problem is on your application overall?